# Importing a function that uses variables from another file

Tags: python-3.x

I'm not sure how to ask this properly, but I have a lib.py file, in which I have this little snippet of code

```
def dPrint(text):
    global debug
    if debug == True:
        print(text)
```

So, when I do `from lib import *`, it doesn't work, as it cannot find the variable `debug`. Is there any way to get it to use the debug variable in my main file?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit difficult to understand because it does not provide a minimum working example. As it stands, I imagine that the snippet is everything that is present in `lib.py`. If you want to have a the variable name `debug` in `lib.py` as global you should re-arrange your code as

```
global debug
debug = False
def dPrint(text):
    if debug == True:
        print(text)
```

This way, when you import `lib.py`, it will interpret the `debug` variable as a global whose default value is `False`. You can change this value afterwards as follows:

```
import lib
lib.debug = True
lib.dPrint('foo')
```

---

To import all the content from `lib.py` and still be able to control the value of the `lib.py` `debug` variable, you can define a `toggle_debug` function in `lib.py` as follows

**lib.py**

```
debug = False
def dPrint(text):
    if debug == True:
        print(text)

def toggle_debug(forced_value=None):
    global debug
    if forced_value is None:
        debug = not debug
    else:
        debug = forced_value
```

**other script**

```
from lib import *
dPrint('foo')    # Nothing gets printed
toggle_debug()
dPrint('foo')    # 'foo' gets printed
toggle_debug(True)
dPrint('foo')    # 'foo' gets printed
toggle_debug()
dPrint('foo')    # Nothing gets printed
toggle_debug(False)
dPrint('foo')    # Nothing gets printed
```

Comment: the `global debug` isn't actually needed

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen In the present snippet it is not needed, but the op could have a function inside `lib.py` which modified `debug`'s value, and to have that change performed on `lib.py`'s `debug`, it needs the `global`

Comment: Yeah that's what I said, it isn't needed...? :P

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen, sorry, when I was writting the comment I hit enter to autocomplete the @ but it posted the unfinished version

Comment: The thing is, I want the debug variable to be in my main file as I will be using lib.py for lots of different files. Is this possible?

Comment: @Lindsay, apparently the function defined in `lib.py` will always refer to the package level `debug` variable. If you want to be able to change `lib`'s `debug` variable from outside the lib package, I recommend that you add a function called `toggle_debug` to `lib.py`. I'll edit my answer to show this.